# How to fix LNK2019 unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++

I have a very simple threading class I'm using for a project. I've just begin progress on it but I'm stuck because of a LNK2019 error I can't figure out how to fix. I've narrowed down the problem to a single line. Perhaps someone can help guide me on what I need to do to fix it.

The following is the class I'm making:

```
#ifndef __THREADING_H
#define __THREADING_H

#include <Windows.h>

class Threading {

public:

    virtual void run() = 0;

    void start();
    void stop();

    bool isStopped();
    void cleanup();

private:
    bool stopped;
    HANDLE reference;
    static DWORD WINAPI start_helperfunction(LPVOID ptr);

};

#endif // __THREADING_H
```

And the line where I'm getting the error is by 2nd line of the `start_helperfunction`, with the `Threading::start_helperfunction` below:

```
#include "Threading.h"

void Threading::start()
{
    stopped = false;
    reference = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Threading::start_helperfunction, this, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Finally the error message I'm getting is:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: static unsigned long __stdcall Threading::start_helperfunction(void *)" (?start_helperfunction@Threading@@CGKPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Threading::start(void)" (?start@Threading@@QAEXXZ)
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong or what to try. I'm sure it's a simple fix. I'm not the most experienced in C++.

Comment: and where is the code defining `start_helperfunction`  ?

Comment: The dog ate it. Or he dropped his phone in the toilet and it had the only copy.

Comment: Also, identifiers starting with `__` are reserved for use by the implementation. Change `__THREADING_H` to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't implement `start_helperfunction`, so the linker can't find it. You need to actually write a static member function with that name. The simplest possible one might look like this:

```
DWORD WINAPI Threading::start_helperfunction(LPVOID ptr)
{
    return 0;
}
```